# Measuring external hdd's rough handling

Tags: hard-drive, usb, smart, measurement

An external USB hard drive periodically travels to and from my facility to update its files (it's for offsite backup).  HDD, not SSD.  How can I measure if it's being handled too roughly?  I'd rather not just wait for the bearings to start squealing.

Manufacturers specify (switched off) shock tolerance in G's in a frequency range (Hz), presumably in the worst-case direction, parallel to the axis of rotation, where a head might contact a platter.

- Can an unpowered HDD itself remember mechanical shocks, somehow?  [**Edit:** Unlikely.  SMART attribute 191 "mechanical shock" says nothing about detection while unpowered.]
- Can degraded benchmark performance indicate rough handling?  (Can rough handling cause symptoms gentler than catastrophic failure?)
- Crazy-glue a [high-G accelerometer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9332) to the disk chassis, wired to an Arduino data logger while traveling?

Comment: Buy an SSD or choose a disk and enclosure that will accurately report SMART data. It's an offsite backup, right? Just buy two disks and call it a day.

Comment: Do you expect the drives to be dropped from 10,000 feet?!

Comment: The terminal velocity of a hard disk hasn't been published, not even by Randall Munroe.  But a drop from just 0.01 per cent of that height onto a sufficiently inelastic surface would void an HDD's warranty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ruggedized hard drive purpose-built technologies like **[RDX](http://www.tandbergdata.com/us/index.cfm/products/media/rdx-media/)** exist...

This seems silly to worry about the handling of the drive. If it *really* is a problem, are you sure it's not a people issue? If it DOES require a technological solution, Google "ruggedized hard drive".

There are plenty of options in the consumer and enterprise realms for this.

Comment: Answer accepted.  1. I hear only crickets about rough handling measurably degrading rather than destroying an HDD.  2. RDX's greater $/TB over non-ruggedized external HDDs isn't much more than recording rough handling by particular people.  So make the technology fit the user's behavior, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

While it may make sense to use an external HDD to transfer from your onsite location to your offsite location, **you should not be using an external HDD *as* your offsite backup.**

Comment: Many reviews of external HDDs say that they can play this role.  Are these reviewers misinformed?

Comment: Actually external HDDs are quite suitable for off-site backups in many cases. I suggest using more than one though. By having one HDD always attached the backups can be automized. One drive at a time could be on safe location while third one travels.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Such was my meaning, though it appears I was not clear enough.